# How to use ta-lib library for technical analysis with C++

Tags: c++, ta-lib, technical-indicator

I am trying to do some technical analysis of [this data](https://ethercalc.org/fo128cmznr) using [ta-lib](http://ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html) library in C++. The problem with `ta-lib` is that there is very few(most probably none except documentation) tutorials regarding their usage in C++. I converted the `open` values (third/C-th column) in the spreadsheet to a vector double `vec` of size 124. I want to use this vector for the calculation of EMA and RSI of 10 day period. This is

```
    //headers used
    #include <vector>
    #include <ta-lib/ta_libc.h>
    std::vector <double> vec;

    //Technical analysis part of the code
    int n=vec.size();  //size of the vector
    std::cout <<"size "<< n  << ' ';
    TA_RetCode retCode;
    retCode = TA_Initialize( );
    if( retCode != TA_SUCCESS )
        std::cout<<"Cannot initialize TA-Lib !\n"<< retCode <"\n";
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"TA-Lib correctly initialized.\n" ;

        /* ... other TA-Lib functions can be used here. */
        double ma=TA_MA(0,n,vec,10,TA_MAType_EMA);
        double rsi=TA_RSI(0,n,vec,10);
        std::cout <<"EMA "<< ma <<"\n";
        std::cout <<"RSI "<< rsi <<"\n";
        TA_Shutdown();
    }
```

The error is

> error: cannot convert ‘std::vector’ to ‘const double*’ for
>   argument ‘3’ to ‘TA_RetCode TA_MA(int, int, const double*, int,
>   TA_MAType, int*, int*, double*)

Comment: Don't spam tags! C++ is not C is not C++.

Comment: Dear olaf but C++ and C are related and same ta-lib library is also used in C.  So aren't they relevant ?

Comment: As C# and Cobol are related, too, because they all start with the same letter. Please show me a C compiler which can generate that error message! (And address comments properly. Take the [tour])

Comment: @Olaf I agree but we can run c and cpp codes together `#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 std::cout<<"hello ";
 printf("world");
 return 0;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code is completely wrong.

1. If you want to stick with `std::vector` you need to pass
   `vec.data()` to TA-Lib's functions instead of `vec`.
2. Why do you think `TA_MA()` returns MA value? They all return
   `TA_RetCode` with `TA_SUCCESS` or error code. It's stated in error
   message you provide and in
   [documentation](http://ta-lib.org/d_api/d_api.html#Direct%20call%20to%20a%20TA%20Function).
   And there is a good sample of how to call such function with static
   arrays.
3. Why you think you can ignore last 3 parameters of `TA_MA` which is a
   pointer to array where results should be stored (result is array of
   moving MAs and its indexes)? If you want stick to
   `std::vector<double>` you must declare one for results and prefill
   it with enough number of values (to allocate memory for storage).
   Then you can use `std::vector<double>::data()` again.

Comment: The sarcasm was not a necessary part of the answer